# IconButton is not displayed on screen

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have just started to learn React.js and material-ui. I was using [this](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/icon-button) to display an icon on screen. However the icon is not displayed on the screen and the screen appears to be blank.

Here is my code:

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import {IconButtonExampleSimple} from './IconButtonExampleSimple.js';


 class App extends  React.Component{

 render()
 {
   return(
         <MuiThemeProvider>
         <IconButtonExampleSimple />
         </MuiThemeProvider>
         );
  }
 }




    ReactDOM.render(
                    <App/>,
                    document.getElementById('root')
                    );
```

**IconButtonExampleSimple.js**

```
  import React from 'react';
  import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
   export class IconButtonExampleSimple extends React.Component{

   render ()
  {
   return (<div>
             <IconButton iconClassName="muidocs-icon-custom-github" />
             <IconButton iconClassName="muidocs-icon-custom-github" 
             disabled={true} />
           </div>
          );
   }
   }
```

Comment: If you use the Dev Tools Inspector, do you see any generated output?

Comment: I know I might not be answering your question, but I would suggest that you use the `v1-beta` version of Material-UI, as the stability and quality of the project has gotten way, way better, and the v1 release is soon, so you won't have to migrate from v0.20.0 to v1!

Comment: @Antoine How can I use the v1-beta version? Right now I am learning from  http://material-ui.com

Comment: @PushpinderSinghGrewal you can go to http://material-ui-next.com for the documentation. If you still have the same question afterall, feel free to ask me.

Comment: By the way, did you include `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">` in your index.html?

Comment: @Antoine Yes, I forgot to include that. Wish you told me that yesterday, I went bananas over this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your index.html

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icon‌​s" rel="stylesheet">
```

You are including the Material-UI part of the icon buttons but those are refering to google's Material-Icons so you must link it in your index file.

Comment: Yeah I know and I did that yesterday . Thanks for helping me out though